# Javascript Onclick with Table Rows

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events

I am having problems with my JScript code.  I am trying to loop through all of the rows in a table and add an `onclick` event.  I can get the `onclick` event to add but have a couple of problems.

The first problem is that all rows end up getting set up with the wrong parameter for the `onclick` event.

The second problem is that it only works in IE.

Here is the code excerpt:

```
shanesObj.addTableEvents = function(){
table = document.getElementById("trackerTable");
for(i=1; i<table.getElementsByTagName("tr").length; i++){
    row = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i];
    orderID = row.getAttributeNode("id").value;
    alert("before onclick: " + orderID);
    row.onclick=function(){shanesObj.tableRowEvent(orderID);};
}}

shanesObj.tableRowEvent = function(orderID){
alert(orderID);}
```

The table is located at the following location...

http://www.blackcanyonsoftware.com/OrderTracker/testAJAX.html

The id's of each row in sequence are...  95, 96, 94...

For some reason, when `shanesObj.tableRowEvent` is called, the `onclick` is set up for all rows with the last value id that went through iteration on the loop (94).

I added some alerts to the page to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a function is called in javascript, the first thing that happens is  that the interpreter sets the scope chain to the state it was in when the function was defined. In your case the scope chain looks like:

```
   GLOBAL
     |
CAll addTableEvents 
     |
CALL onclick
```

So when the variable *orderID* is stumbled upon by the javascript interpreter it searches the scope chain for that variable. There is no *orderID* defined inside your *onclick* function, so the next spot to look is inside *addTableEvents*. You would think *orderID* is defined here, but since you did not declare *orderID* with the var keyword, *orderID* became a global variable, so *orderID* is not found inside *addTableEvents*. The last spot to look is inside GLOBAL, and sure enough it is there, and its value is the last one which it was assigned, and in this case its the last value of *orderID = row.getAttributeNode("id").value;* in the for loop.

To see this more clearly look at the following

```
shanesObj.addTableEvents = function(){
table = document.getElementById("trackerTable");
for(i=1; i<table.getElementsByTagName("tr").length; i++){
        row = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i];
        orderID = row.getAttributeNode("id").value;
        alert("before onclick: " + orderID);
        row.onclick=function(){var orderID = orderID; shanesObj.tableRowEvent(orderID);};
}
orderID = -1;
}

shanesObj.tableRowEvent = function(orderID){
alert(orderID);
}
```

The result of a click here will always be -1.

So, to get around this problem, I suggest you drop all the extra and unneeded code and use something like the following,

```
for(i=1; i<table.getElementsByTagName("tr").length; i++){
        row = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i];
        row.onclick=function(){shanesObj.tableRowEvent(this.id);};

}
```

Just access the id attribute directly from the called object.

P.S. I have no idea why your code doesn't work in IE (it worked in my IE7).

Comment: Thank you. This worked very well, and it also helped me understand the problem.

Comment: P.S.  This does work in Firefox and IE now that the code has been corrected.  Thanks again!

Comment: Just a note to add something that caught me out: if you are re-generating your table regularly, via a regular AJAX poll for example, don't forget to re-add the listeners each time. Also, the index appears to need to start at 0 if you are looking at 'td' - not sure of this is the case for 'tr' also.

Answer (score 2):

Why not attach the event handler to the table and grab the rowindex of the cell that fired the click event inside the click handler.

Answer (score -1):

y'cant get much simpler than this!
can obviously be used with dynamically built rows.
lots of love,
sb.

```
<html>

<head>
<title></title>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
var TO,URL;
function Link(url){
 URL=url;
 TO=setTimeout('window.location=URL;',500);
}
//-->
</script>
</head>

<body>

<tr onclick="Link('anotherpage.html');">
<td>row1 cell1</td>
<td>row1 cell2</td>
</tr>

<tr onclick="Link('yetanotherpage.html');">
<td>row2 cell3</td>
<td>row2 cell4</td>
</tr>

</body>

</html>
```